# 2D image is rendering on a vertical plane, horizontally. Why?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I am creating an AR application. I am trying to render a test image on a vertical plane (my monitor).

I have setup an ugmented images database and have it working correctly. I can find the image in a camera view and when it finds the correct hitpoints it will render my 2D image.

The problem I'm having is the rotation is wrong and I am unsure why. I would like the image to render vertically as if it was being shown on my monitor but when it renders it's of horizontal orientation from the center of the scanned image (see image below).

[image: Orientation]

Here is my ARCamera class:

```
package com.example.prco.ui.arcamera;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.prco.R;
import com.google.ar.core.Anchor;
import com.google.ar.core.AugmentedImage;
import com.google.ar.core.AugmentedImageDatabase;
import com.google.ar.core.Config;
import com.google.ar.core.Frame;
import com.google.ar.core.Session;
import com.google.ar.core.TrackingState;
import com.google.ar.core.exceptions.UnavailableApkTooOldException;
import com.google.ar.core.exceptions.UnavailableArcoreNotInstalledException;
import com.google.ar.core.exceptions.UnavailableSdkTooOldException;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.AnchorNode;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ArSceneView;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.FrameTime;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.AnimationData;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.ModelRenderable;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.Renderable;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.ViewRenderable;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.TransformableNode;
import com.google.common.collect.Sets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Collection;

public class ArCamera extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = ArCamera.class.getSimpleName();
    Session mSession;
    private ArFragment arFragment;
    private ArSceneView arSceneView;
    private ModelRenderable modelRenderable;
    private boolean modelAdded = false;
    private boolean sessionConfigured = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_arcamera);
        arFragment = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ar_fragment);

        arFragment.getPlaneDiscoveryController().hide();
        arFragment.getPlaneDiscoveryController().setInstructionView(null);
        arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addOnUpdateListener(this::onUpdateFrame);

        arSceneView = arFragment.getArSceneView();

    }

    private boolean setupAugmentedImageDatabase(Config config) {
        AugmentedImageDatabase augmentedImageDatabase;

        Bitmap augmentedImageBitmap = loadAugmentedImage();
        if (augmentedImageBitmap == null) {
            return false;
        }

        augmentedImageDatabase = new AugmentedImageDatabase(mSession);
        augmentedImageDatabase.addImage("logoGrey", augmentedImageBitmap);

        config.setAugmentedImageDatabase(augmentedImageDatabase);
        config.setFocusMode(Config.FocusMode.AUTO);
        return true;
    }

    private Bitmap loadAugmentedImage() {
        try (InputStream is = getAssets().open("logoGrey.png")) {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IO Exception!", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void onUpdateFrame(FrameTime frameTime) {
        Frame frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();

        Collection<AugmentedImage> augmentedImages = frame.getUpdatedTrackables(AugmentedImage.class);

        for (AugmentedImage augmentedImage : augmentedImages) {
            if (augmentedImage.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {
                if (augmentedImage.getName().contains("logoGrey") && !modelAdded) {
                    renderObject(arFragment, augmentedImage.createAnchor(augmentedImage.getCenterPose()), R.layout.ar_test);
                    modelAdded = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void renderObject(ArFragment fragment, Anchor anchor, int model) {
        ViewRenderable.builder().setView(this, model).build().thenAccept(renderable -> addNodeToScene(fragment, anchor, renderable));
    }

//    private void renderObject(ArFragment fragment, Anchor anchor, int model) {
//        ModelRenderable.builder()
//                .setSource(this, model)
//                .build()
//                .thenAccept(renderable -> addNodeToScene(fragment, anchor, renderable))
//                .exceptionally((throwable -> {
//                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
//                    builder.setMessage(throwable.getMessage())
//                            .setTitle("Error!");
//                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
//                    dialog.show();
//                    return null;
//                }));
//    }

    private void addNodeToScene(ArFragment fragment, Anchor anchor, Renderable renderable){
        AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
        TransformableNode node = new TransformableNode(fragment.getTransformationSystem());
        node.setRenderable(renderable);
        node.setParent(anchorNode);
        fragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(anchorNode);
        node.select();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mSession != null) {

            arSceneView.pause();
            mSession.pause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mSession == null) {
            String message = null;
            Exception exception = null;
            try {
                mSession = new Session(this);
            } catch (UnavailableArcoreNotInstalledException
                    e) {
                message = "Please install ARCore";
                exception = e;
            } catch (UnavailableApkTooOldException e) {
                message = "Please update ARCore";
                exception = e;
            } catch (UnavailableSdkTooOldException e) {
                message = "Please update android";
                exception = e;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                message = "AR is not supported";
                exception = e;
            }

            if (message != null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception creating session", exception);
                return;
            }
            sessionConfigured = true;

        }
        if (sessionConfigured) {
            configureSession();
            sessionConfigured = false;

            arSceneView.setupSession(mSession);
        }

    }

    private void configureSession() {
        Config config = new Config(mSession);
        if (!setupAugmentedImageDatabase(config)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to setup augmented", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        config.setUpdateMode(Config.UpdateMode.LATEST_CAMERA_IMAGE);
        mSession.configure(config);
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong, and how would I make the image sit in the correct orientation on my monitor (vertically)? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I added `node.setLocalRotation(Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(-1f, 0, 0), 90f));` to my addNodeToScene and now my images orientation is correct.